# iOS 7 - Behavior of dynamic wallpapers for custom UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios7, xcode5

I have been fiddling around with the new Xcode 5 GM and UIDynamics to create an effect like the new "Bubble" Wallpaper on the iPhone Dashboard.

I want basically the same thing. certain Images added as a subview inside a custom UIView and added as an UIDynamicItem to a UIGravityBehavior to a UIDynamicAnimator. But still it does not seem to really work.

**Main ViewController**

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            self.image = [[MYImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 200, 200, 200)];
            [self.view addSubview:self.image];
            UIDynamicAnimator *dynamicAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
            UIGravityBehavior *gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] init];
            [dynamicAnimator addBehavior:gravity];
            [gravity addItem:self.image];
            self.view.alpha = 0.5f;
        }
        return self;
    }
```

**MYImageView.h**

```
    @interface NoteView : UIView <UIDynamicItem>

    @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGRect bounds;
    @property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint center;
    @property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGAffineTransform transform;
```

In the .m I just create an ImageView and add it to self as a subview. The bounds of self will be returned as double the size of the imageView added.

I get no errors and the App shows up fine, but I don't get any gravitational reaction.

Thanks for the help!
Benzy

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my github project showing how to use UIDynamic features in iOS 7:
I hope it helps ;)

https://github.com/debris/AIMBalloon